# node.js ES6 how to pass value to html element

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class

I want to create qrcode with es6, I want to pass the return value of function `generateQR()` to `<img>` element,but I got a 404 error, how can I fix that
here is my code:

```js
// index.js:
const QRcode = require('qrcode');
 
class index extends Component{
    generateQR = async text => {
      let qrSrc = "";
      try {
        qrSrc = await QRcode.toDataURL(text);
      } catch(err){
          console.log(err);
      }
      return qrSrc;
    }

    render(){ 
        return(
                <div>
                <img src={this.generateQR("www.hello.world")}/>
                <div/>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`generateQR` is async. It returns a promise. You should use a `state` and re-render the component when the QR is ready:

Create a separate component that generates the QR code.

```
// components/QRCode.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { toDataURL } from "qrcode";

function QRCode({ text }) {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState("data:image/gif");

  useEffect(() => {
    toDataURL(text).then((qr) => setSrc(qr));
  }, [text]);

  return <img src={src} alt="qr" />;
}

export default QRCode
```

And then import and use it like

```
<QRCode text="hello world"/>
```